# How to execute `zz` command after each Jedi jump to defenition command?

Tags: autocmd, plugin-jedi-vim

I am using `davidhalter/jedi-vim` plugin to navigate through Python definitions. If a definition is in the same file, the cursor is placed at the top or bottom of the screen. In these cases I usually press `zz` to center the view. I wonder is it possible to automatically execute `zz` after each jump?

Jedi-vim has this option:

```
let g:jedi#goto_command = "<leader>d"
```

But I guess its not the place where I should do the change to add `zz` after that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the plugin's code you'll find that the mapping is done [like this](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/5d461570/ftplugin/python/jedi.vim#L11):

```
execute 'nnoremap <buffer> '.g:jedi#goto_command.' :call jedi#goto()<CR>'
```

So what you can do is override that with your own `ftplugin` ([`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)) and your own mapping. You could create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` this is a file which will be executed when a buffer has the filetype `python` set. In this file you can reuse the original mapping but add `zz` at the end:

```
execute 'nnoremap <buffer> '.g:jedi#goto_command.' :call jedi#goto()<CR>zz'
```

And that should do what you want.